# Vue JS code is not updating inside a loop

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm stuck with a problem for a couple of days now and I've no idea what might be the solution. I've tried a couple, nothing worked.

I'm trying to enlarge a span text to fit the parent container width.

I've tried this.$forceUpdate();, didn't work.
I've also tried to pause the loop, but I found out later that that's not really possible in JS.

```html
<template>
  <span 
    ref="textRowRef" 
    v-bind:style="{fontSize: fontSize + 'px'}" >

    {{ textRow }}</span>
</template>
```

```js
// this is the VueJS code
var textRow = this.$refs.textRowRef;
    var parentRow = textRow.parentElement;

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.fontSize += 10;

        console.log(`Text Row in loop: ${textRow.clientWidth}`);

        textRow = this.$refs.textRowRef;
    }
console.log(`Text Row: ${textRow.clientWidth}`);
console.log(`Parent Row: ${parentRow.clientWidth}`);
```

Results in the console:

> 10 Text Row in loop: 48
>   Text Row: 48
>   Parent Row: 378

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt.

I set `fontSize` to `72px` then gradually reduce it by `1px` until the text fits within the box. For such a simple example the performance is fine but I suspect that in the context of a larger page reducing it by `1px` each time might prove too slow.

Each time the `fontSize` changes it triggers a re-render. The `updated` hook then measures the text to decide whether it needs to be shrunk even further.

If the text changes it resets the size to `72px` and starts the process over again. I've not made any attempt to track the size of the parent element but it would also need to perform a reset if the width of that element changed.

I've added `whitespace: nowrap` to the `<span>` to ensure that its width will overflow the parent element. Otherwise the text would just wrap when the width reaches the edge of the parent element.

```js
const MAX_FONT_SIZE = 72

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      fontSize: MAX_FONT_SIZE,
      textRow: 'Initial value for the text'
    }
  },

  watch: {
    textRow: 'resetSize'
  },

  mounted () {
    this.refreshSize()
  },
  
  updated () {
    this.refreshSize()
  },

  methods: {
    async refreshSize () {
      await this.$nextTick()
      
      const textRow = this.$refs.textRowRef
      const parentRow = textRow.parentElement
      
      if (textRow.offsetWidth > parentRow.clientWidth) {
        this.fontSize = Math.max(8, this.fontSize - 1)
      }
    },
    
    resetSize () {
      if (this.fontSize === MAX_FONT_SIZE) {
        this.refreshSize()
      } else {
        this.fontSize = MAX_FONT_SIZE
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.text-span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span 
    ref="textRowRef"
    class="text-span"
    :style="{fontSize: fontSize + 'px'}"
  >
    {{ textRow }}
  </span>
  <br>
  Edit: <input v-model="textRow">
</div>
```